# jsLint still giving warning "X was used before it was defined." even when undef is set

Tags: javascript, jslint

recently a typo in a js file caused a problem on one of my projects, but only on certain browsers. I'm trying to run most of our js files through jsLint to look for any other un-detected problems. The goal is to get all of our js files to pass jsLint either by correcting the issue or if I'm ok with the issue then turning on the appropriate jsLint option.

If I can do that, then in the future I would like to find a way to run jsLint more often, but first I need to get all the files passing.

I'm having a lot of trouble with one issue though. I keep getting the warning/error that "X was used before it was defined." I'm ok with using items before they are defined, so I wanted to turn this warning off. I've tried setting undef: true in the comment at the top and setting the checkbox through the web interface but as of today, I'm still getting this error.

Is this option broken or am I doing something wrong or mis-understanding what this option does.

According to the [docs](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html), this should work on functions.

I'm currently using the jsLint [web tool](http://jslint.com/) to scan the code below.

```
/*jslint undef: true, white: true, browser: true */
/*global jQuery */

(function($){
    "use strict";

    $(function() {
        createDashboard();
        loadDashboardDataFromControls();
    });

    function loadDashboardDataFromControls()
    {
    }

    function createDashboard()
    {
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [JSLint source code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/421db19f9242546d461dd9f68b381583112a04c5/jslint.js#L2404) (latest commit as of this writing), `undef` is sef to `false` in *strict mode*:

```
function use_strict() {
    if (next_token.string === 'use strict') {
        if (strict_mode) {
            warn('unnecessary_use');
        }
        edge();
        advance();
        semicolon();
        strict_mode = true;
        option.undef = false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As I assume you are aware of, you could easily avoid the warning by rearranging your source code. Simply move `loadDashboardDataFromControls()` and `loadDashboardDataFromControls()` above `$([...])`.

Note: While in *strict mode*, variables need to be defined before being used, your code obviously *does not* violate that rule. So, in my opinion, what we see is at least a documentation bug: JSLint documentation should state that in strict mode, the `undef` flag is set to `false`.

Comment: yeah, I could get rid of the warning by re-ordering the code, but I really prefer the $(function() { ... }); to be at the top where it is easy to find.  You were right about strict mode. I tested this by removing "use strict"; from the js and adding the jslint option sloppy to tollerate that. I'm no longer getting the message about using those methods before they are declared, but its still lists both methods as both undefined and unused which seems contradictory. I'm marking your answer as correct since your answer is excellent, but I don't suppose you could also tell me how to remove this er

Comment: You could rewrite your code as `var createDashboard; /* ... */ createDashboard = function () { /* ... */ };`. That's a clean solution, somewhat akin to *C* where you define prototypes first.

Answer (score 0):

To disable this message, you may create a .jshintrc file in the root of your project and add the code:

```
{
   "latedef": false
}
```